Are there any examples of an analytic proposition that can only be stated with the full the predicate calculus?
I'm using a variation on the old meaning of "analytic" where an analytic proposition represents a relationship between concepts and doesn't directly reference objects at all. For convenience, I'm going to represent a concept in curly braces {like this}. So {bachelor} represents the concept of being a bachelor. I'll use the less-than sign to represent that one concept is included in or entailed by another concept; for example, {unmarried} < {bachelor} says that the concept of being unmarried is entailed by the concept of being a bachelor. My notion of an analytic statement is that an analytic statement is one that can be expressed entirely as intensional relationships between concepts in this way.
There are extensional relations between concepts as well. For example, "all warm blooded creatures have a liver" expresses an extensional relationship between concepts in the sense that it says that every object that actually falls under the concept {warm blooded} also happens to fall under the concept {has a liver}, but this statement, while true is not analytic because you have to examine objects to know if the relationship holds. The relationship is an accident, a contingent relationship that might have been different if the world had been different, so it is not built into the concepts themselves.
There are other intensional relationships that hold between concepts. For example, {married} # {bachelor} where I'm using the symbol # to represent the relationship that two concepts are incompatible with each other. Or {warm blooded} <> {has a liver} where <> represents that two concepts are not related by either entailment or incompatibility.
So here's my question: can all possible analytic relationships between concepts be expressed with an algebra based on operators like <, #, and <>, or do we need the full complexity of predicate logic? For example, are there examples of relationships between concepts where we would have to say something like the following?
the relationship between concepts X, Y, and Z is that
  necessarily for all x in X, y in Y, and z in Z .
    <some complex expression>

ADDENDUM:
After I wrote this question, I discovered that Leibniz had already come up with a nearly identical algebra of concepts: https://iep.utm.edu/leib-log/#SH3a. There is nothing new under the sun.

If I understand this right your concepts are only those expressible by one-place predicates, so monadic calculus is enough. It is strictly weaker than full predicate calculus and essentially reduces to Boolean algebra with inclusion. However, it cannot even express axioms of Euclidean geometry because they involve binary and ternary relations. For example, "of three points on a line one and only one is between the other two" needs a two-place predicate for incidence to a line and a three-place predicate for betweenness.

@Conifold, your comment sound so familiar that I'm wondering if I asked this question before.

@DavidGudeman Here is an old example of an inference which you can make in predicate logic but not in older forms of logic (e.g. propositional or syllogistic): "All cats are animals. Hence all the tails of cats are tails of animals." I don't quite follow how you are defining your operators, but you know how you mean for them to work. If you decorate the "All cats are animals..." inference with curly brackets and operator symbols in an appropriate way, do you get an example of what you're asking for?

Your proposed 3-operator algebraic logic only can express up to propositional logic. Also conditional entailments as your example may not always be contingent, math theorems are full of these necessarily which your logic cannot express without quantifiers or their alternative types…

There are plenty of two-place predicate examples. If A is married to B then B is married to A. If A is north of B then B is south of A. If you want one with existential rather than universal quantifiers, how about: If something is a daughter then something is a mother.

@Bumble, yea, I realized that after thinking about Conifold's comment. Even worse, I realized that I had realized that before and forgotten it. My brain isn't what it used to be.

@DoubleKnot, yes, that was the thrust of my question, whether I needed more than an analog to propositional logic. The question for one-place predicates was answered by an article (linked in the question now) about Leibniz's calculus of concepts. The answer for two-place was fairly obvious once I started thinking about it--I do need something like the predicate calculus.

I believe arity is not the thrust of your confusion about your toy logic algebra while analytic conditional entailment even totally within monadic calculus is, whereabout your toy cannot express. No wonder if you were able to completely understand your thrust once before, you won't forget this time...

I deleted my response because I radically misapphreneded your ask. Is the<,#,<> notation you use homebrew? Or is it Fregean. I find the syntactic approach to concepts interesting but I'm afraid I'm ignorant on the topic.

@JD, I invented and wrote up an extensive algebra of concepts several years ago when I was interested in intensional logic and couldn't find one in the literature that was genuinely intensional in the Fregean sense (in particular, modality cannot substitute for intensionality). But as I noted in my addendum, it turns out that Leibniz had already done almost exactly the same thing a few centuries ago, at least as regards properties. I now recall that I had added relations to my system, and that I discovered then that I needed something more like predicate logic.

@DavidGudeman Thanks! I took a look at the IEP article, so if you rediscovered Leibniz system, a tip o' the hat. It's fascinating to see how far back some of the "contemporary" research really goes, and always a mystery as to how little of this stuff gets noticed and taught.

@JD, well, when Leibniz did it, it was startlingly original. When I did it, it was just puttering round in a well-mowed field.
